# check a column in each row and capture each unique value and assign to a variable

Tags: excel, vba

I have the following code that loops through each row and executes code to change values. I also want it to capture the processor's name located in column C for each row but I don't want duplicate names. I will then use those names for an automated email code I have prepared. I don't know how to capture the names into a variable for each row without duplicates.

```
Dim x as Integer
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
      NumRows = Range("A2", Range("A2").End(xlDown)).Rows.Count
      Range("A2").Select
      For x = 2 To NumRows + 1
         Range("A" & x).Validation.Delete
         If ActiveSheet.Range("T" & x).Value > 1 Then ActiveSheet.Range("G" & x).Value = "YES" ' Else
         If ActiveSheet.Range("T" & x).Value < 1 Then ActiveSheet.Range("G" & x).Value = "NO" ' Else

'HERE IS WHERE I WANT TO ADD THE CODE I NEED HELP WITH

         ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
      Next
      Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```

[image]

Comment: Sounds like you want a dictionary or a collection.

Comment: Not sure if that is what I need and I just realized in my screen shot example I don't show any of the processors duplicated. I only show a small sample but in reality one processor can be listed multiple times and it wouldn't make sense for me to have the same name over and over in the email .to section.

Answer (score 0):

A collection is very easy to use for this application.

In the loop through the cells, you can loop through the collection and check for duplicates. Then use a boolean to set if there is a duplicate or not, and thus if to add the value to the collection or not.
Here is an example structure, without variable names.

[x] = var

```
Dim [collection] As New Collection, [cell] as Range, [range] as Range, [boolean] as Boolean, [item] as Variant

For Each [cell] In [range]
    [boolean] = False
    For Each [item] In [collection]
        If [item] = [cell].Value Then
            [boolean] = True
            Exit For
        End If
    Next [item]
    If [boolean] = False Then [collection].Add [cell].Value
Next [cell]
```

Then you can read all the items with for loop again:

```
For Each [item] In [collection]
    Debug.Print [item]
next [item]
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

```
Option Explicit

Sub TEST()

    Dim LastRow1 As Long, i As Long
    Dim dict As New Scripting.Dictionary

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

        'Find Last row of sheet 1 column C
        LastRow1 = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row

        'Start looping rows from row 2 to lastrow1
        For i = 2 To LastRow1

            'If item not exist in in dictionary
            If Not dict.Exists(.Range("C" & i).Value) Then

                'If dictionary is empty
                If dict.Count = 0 Then
                    dict.Add .Range("C" & i).Value, dict.Count
                Else
                    dict.Add .Range("C" & i).Value, dict.Count + 1
                End If

            End If

        Next i

    End With

End Sub
```